# Cakephp - automatically run app model callback with models callback

Tags: cakephp, callback

I have callback functions in AppModel.php, and also for some models, is there is way to automatically call the app model callback with (preferably before) the current model's callback is being called.

e.g. lets say I have `beforeSave` in AppModel, for each beforeSave function in my models I have to put 
`parent::beforeSave($options)` in it. Now, can I make it at once for all models, so I will not have to put in each callback in each model.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope.

Because your Model extends AppModel, any of these callback functions will override the parent function. You will always have to manually call the parent function.